# QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I set a QT menu, which is automatically connected with action function `on_actionOpen_triggered()`. Later I want to pass a filename string to this function in order to call this function manually in a special condition. So I changed the function signature to `on_actionOpen_triggered( const char *filename_in )`. After this change the program is running well, but there is a complain in terminal,

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionOpen_triggered(const char*)

I am wondering what happened, and how I can add arguments for this menu action functions.

Thank you.

Comment: Kind of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460421/pyside-qmetaobject-connectslotsbyname-emits-warnings-no-matching-signal-bu and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992550/getting-errors-when-using-qt-creator-to-create-signals-and-slots

Answer (score 19):

I was facing same `Warning/Error`  **QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for**

And got simple solution.
For Example:

**Problem :**
`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionOpen_triggered(const char*)` Warning
You just need to change the name of the `Slot`

**Solution**
Change Slot name like `on_actionOpenTriggered` and this warning disappear.

**Hint**
Qt try to understand its default slot like `on_<name_of_object>_<action>`, So if you specify any slot with above signature, Qt will throw warning.

Hope it will help to someone.

Comment: Oddly enough changing the name of the slot to camel case works.

Answer (score 9):

Qt autoconnection mechanism can't find suitable signal to your slot. For menu item there's no signal that would match your slot with one argument, and signal **must not** have fewer arguments than slot.

You can change slot's name so that it won't try to find a matching signal, and use `QObject::connect` directly instead of `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`. Moreover you'll have to assign default value to your argument `filename_in` if you want `connect` to work with `triggered`signal.

Comment: What do we need to change on the slot's name so that it won't try to find a matching signal?

Comment: It seems you just shouldn't name your manual slots "on_something()". Try creating a function named "on_something()" in the "slots:" part of your class, don't connect it to anything, and you'll see that Qt will still try to create a connection. So, the only slots with the name starting with "on_" should be the ones auto-generated by Qt creator.

Comment: @vsz, Please add your comment as an answer to this question. This solves the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with PySide6, not with PyQt5.
With PySide6 I got rid of the message by removing the Slot()-decorators.