# Qt 5.9 slot naming bug

Tags: c++, qt, qt-slot

I'm using Qt 5.9.

I've a problem declaring slots with underscore style in particular when I name it with more then 2 underscores.For example with a `void on_stop_treatment()` slot, even I don't make a connection, I get `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_stop_treatment()`.

Anyway, making a connection, even if I get the same message, the slot signal mechanism works. Removing the second underscore I get no error message and the mechanism works. (I also tried deleting the moc file and rebuild)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355023/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal)

Comment: This is not a bug, moc to connect some slots created by Qt Designer uses the method [connectSlotsByName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName), this method will try to connect any slot that has the format `on_<object>_<signal>`, and in your case your slot has that format so it is looking for <object> and <signal> within your class

Comment: But from i've understood from your answer i should get          QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for stop() and not     QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_stop_treatment()

Comment: No, it will try to look for a hypothetical `treatment` signal on a hypothetical `stop` object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring your slot with the name `on_stop_treatment` will clash with the Qt feature called [Signal/Slot Automatic Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections)

Qt will detect this specific syntax for your slot, and will try to match `stop` with a QObject named `stop` and `treatment` with a signal of that name declared in the class of the QObject.

To achieve this, Qt uses internally `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);` to perform automatic signal/slot connections.

Comment: This question is duplicated, there is no need to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355023/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal)

Comment: Nope, OP ask why he get this error when naming his slot like this. Other question from jhy ask why his signal/slot automatic connection doesn't work like he want. There is no duplication here

Comment: Totally OT, but I love your avatar. Milkman Dan is really not appreciated enough at his job (or by Karen).