# Reusing a cmake-built QT project in Visual Studio 2015: "connectSlotsByName: No matching signal"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, code-reuse

As mentioned above my task is to change the code of an existing visual studio project that uses QT 5.7. 
The student who has worked on it before me built his project with cmake with which I am completely unfamiliar, while absolutely having no time to get into, unfortunately.

My first attempt is to set up a new VS-project into which I paste all source files and QT-files necessary.
This has resulted in several problems, one of which was that I had to delete, save and rewrite `Q_OBJECT` in all Q-Classes.

This tells me that the actual workflow is corrupting the project right from the beginning.

With regards to this, my predecessor used `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` to connect signals and slots of Gui-Objects like Buttons. When debugging I get

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_[some Gui Obejct]_clicked()
```

for all of the existing QWidget-Childs in the GUI.

This seems strange, because the signals of such buttons and so on, have to exist in moc-code (the corresponding slots exist of course), correct?

There are a decent amount of Gui-elements existing in the project, so I prefer to not use connect for every single one of them.

Questions:

1.) Is there a recommended workflow, that will enable one to shoot oneself in the foot less often?
2.) In order to enable Qt's Meta-Object-Compiler to create `ui_*.h`'s and `moc_*.cpp`'s it needs `*.ui`'s, `*.qrc`'s, and potential resource files, correct?
3.) To what extent is it possible that the fact that the project was originally built with cmake affects Qt-meta compiling?

Thank you very much in advance

Edit: 
Additional information and code sample of the QMainWindow-Class `Navigation_Gui`.
I added the `connect` line, that produces an excess violation, which I think should not be produced.

```
Navigation_Gui::Navigation_Gui(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent){

this->Storage = new ThreadStorage();                            
this->CamPtr = new CamBar(this->Storage);   
this->NavPtr = new Navigation(this->CamPtr, this->Storage);

ui.setupUi(this);

this->getRegPoints = false;
this->Storage->Log << "Main Gui initialized" << endl;

connect(this->ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked())); }
```

The header

```
#ifndef NAVIGATION_GUI_H
#define NAVIGATION_GUI_H


#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_navigation_gui.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "vtkMatrix4x4.h"
#include <vector>
#include "ThreadStorage.h"

class CamBar;       //forward deklaration  
class Navigation;   //forward declaration 
class ThreadStorage;    //forward declaration


class Navigation_Gui : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Navigation_Gui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Navigation_Gui();

    //! true if Button GetRegPoints is pressed.
    bool getRegPoints;

    public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Navigation_GuiClass ui;
    //! initial CameraPointer
    CamBar* CamPtr;
    //! initial NavigationPointer
    Navigation* NavPtr;
    //! initial LogPointer
    ThreadStorage* Storage;


    private slots:
    // private slots for Gui events
    void on_ConnectButton_clicked();
    void on_RegPointButton_clicked();
    //void on_TrackingButton_clicked();
    void on_QuitButton_clicked();
    void on_NewTrackingButton_clicked();
    void on_getLocatorButton_clicked();
    void on_MHHAbout_clicked();

};
#endif // NAVIGATION_GUI_H
```

And this is the generated Ui-header

```
#ifndef UI_NAVIGATION_GUI_H
#define UI_NAVIGATION_GUI_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Navigation_GuiClass
{
public:
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer;
    QPushButton *ConnectButton;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_2;
    QPushButton *getLocatorButton;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_7;
    QPushButton *RegPointButton;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_3;
    QPushButton *NewTrackingButton;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_4;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_5;
    QPushButton *QuitButton;
    QSpacerItem *verticalSpacer_6;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPushButton *MHHAbout;

    void setupUi(QWidget *Navigation_GuiClass)
    {
        if (Navigation_GuiClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            Navigation_GuiClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("Navigation_GuiClass"));
        Navigation_GuiClass->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
        Navigation_GuiClass->resize(358, 500);
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Navigation_GuiClass->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        Navigation_GuiClass->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        Navigation_GuiClass->setMinimumSize(QSize(358, 458));
        Navigation_GuiClass->setMaximumSize(QSize(358, 500));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(Navigation_GuiClass);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(6);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayout"));
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(6);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
        verticalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer);

        ConnectButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        ConnectButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("ConnectButton"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy1(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(1);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(ConnectButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        ConnectButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        ConnectButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 68));
        QFont font;
        font.setPointSize(14);
        ConnectButton->setFont(font);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(ConnectButton);

        verticalSpacer_2 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_2);

        getLocatorButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        getLocatorButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("getLocatorButton"));
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(getLocatorButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        getLocatorButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        getLocatorButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 68));
        getLocatorButton->setFont(font);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(getLocatorButton);

        verticalSpacer_7 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_7);

        RegPointButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        RegPointButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("RegPointButton"));
        RegPointButton->setEnabled(false);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(RegPointButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        RegPointButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        RegPointButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 68));
        RegPointButton->setFont(font);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(RegPointButton);

        verticalSpacer_3 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_3);

        NewTrackingButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        NewTrackingButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("NewTrackingButton"));
        NewTrackingButton->setEnabled(false);
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(NewTrackingButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        NewTrackingButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        NewTrackingButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 68));
        NewTrackingButton->setFont(font);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(NewTrackingButton);

        verticalSpacer_4 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_4);

        verticalSpacer_5 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_5);

        QuitButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        QuitButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("QuitButton"));
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(QuitButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        QuitButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
        QuitButton->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 68));
        QuitButton->setFont(font);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(QuitButton);

        verticalSpacer_6 = new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

        verticalLayout->addItem(verticalSpacer_6);

        pushButton = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(pushButton);

        MHHAbout = new QPushButton(Navigation_GuiClass);
        MHHAbout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MHHAbout"));
        QIcon icon;
        icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/MainWindow/Resources/60px.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
        MHHAbout->setIcon(icon);
        MHHAbout->setIconSize(QSize(174, 60));

        verticalLayout->addWidget(MHHAbout);


        gridLayout->addLayout(verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1);


        retranslateUi(Navigation_GuiClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Navigation_GuiClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *Navigation_GuiClass)
    {
        Navigation_GuiClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Main Menu - Navigation (CamBar)", 0));
        ConnectButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Connect", 0));
        getLocatorButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Locator Editor", 0));
        RegPointButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Get Registration Points", 0));
        NewTrackingButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Tracking", 0));
        QuitButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "Quit", 0));
        pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Navigation_GuiClass", "PushButton", 0));
        MHHAbout->setText(QString());
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Navigation_GuiClass: public Ui_Navigation_GuiClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif
```

When I change the `connect` line in the constructor above to

```
connect(this->ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

I get

```
QObject::connect: No such slot Navigation_Gui::this->on_pushButton_clicked() in navigation_gui.cpp:26
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'Navigation_GuiClass')
```

Which is also odd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24355288/5366641

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can see, that is not what I am looking for since I do want automatic connection instead of preventing it (the latter seems to be explained in the link).
I cannot find any individual calls of "connect" in the source code of the original project, hence it must have been done automatically.

Comment: I have pasted all of the necessary ui-forms in the project directory. Moc'ing, and such is done succesfully. 
I doubt that ui-forms have a direct influence on how signal-slot-connections will be set up. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right about *.ui's creating connections.
Btw, I am not experiencing these problems when setting up a new project. ConnectSlotsByName and connect work both, in this case.
It must have something to do with wrong information in project files of Visual Studio.

Comment: I added some of the code, I hope that it is helpful.

Comment: Could it be that `on_pushButton_clicked` is declared in _navigation_gui.h_, but not implemented in _navigation_gui.cpp_?

Comment: Apart from that, `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Navigation_GuiClass);` should connect `pushButton` to the corresponding slot automatically, so there is no need to do that manually.

Comment: Yes, the slot is implemented. I thought failure of manual connection could be interesting since it should work in this case regardless, so there is definitely something wrong on a higher level. I will add the vs project file.

Comment: You know, because `No such slot Navigation_Gui::this->on_pushButton_clicked()` means - _no such slot_. So somehow it is not found. It is hard to tell without seeing the whole picture. Also there are some other things, which bother me, as for example the unnecessary use of `this` and the fact, that `ui` is not a pointer.

Comment: Since pushbutton is a pointer it shouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: I agree about that. As for the missing slot, why don't you try to use the Qt5 way of connecting signals to slots. You will get a compile time error if something is wrong.

Comment: instead of `connect(this->ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));` try `connect(this->ui.pushButton, &PushButton::clicked, this, Navigation_Gui::on_pushButton_clicked);`.

Comment: Did you try it? What is the result?

Comment: That does not work. Wrong arguments.
Appreciate your help very much, by the way.

Comment: That was not intened to work, but to give you a compile-time error, which is easier to analyse, than the run-time error, caused by the old way of connecting signals and slots. Please, show the exact error message.