# QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pbZatwierdz_clicked(QString)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect a button's clicked() signal with a slot that gets a QString as parameter. 
How can I solve that?

main:

QObject::connect(&first, SIGNAL(newTextEntered(const QString&)),
                         &second, SLOT(on_pbZatwierdz_clicked((const QString&))));

MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::on_leEdytujKlienta_returnPressed()
{
    emit this->newTextEntered(ui->leEdytujKlienta->text());
}
```

FORM2:

```
void edytujklienta::on_pbZatwierdz_clicked(const QString &text)
{    
    qDebug() << "Received number ID: " << text ; 
}
```

//show your .h and .cpp :),

edytujklienta.cpp code:

```
   void edytujklienta::onpbZatwierdzclicked(const QString &text)
{    
    qDebug() << "ODEBRANO numer ID: " << text ;
    QString Nazwisko;
    Nazwisko=ui->lineNazwisko->text();
    QSqlQuery updateQuery ;
    updateQuery.prepare("UPDATE tKlient SET NAZWISKO = :newNAZWISKO, IMIE = :newIMIE WHERE ID = :id ");
    updateQuery.bindValue(":newIMIE",Imie);
    updateQuery.exec();   
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? use `QObject::connect(&first, &MainWindow::newTextEntered, &second, &edytujklienta::on_pbZatwierdz_clicked)`, read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your question, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355023/qmetaobjectconnectslotsbyname-no-matching-signal)

Comment: simple, change all `on_pbZatwierdz_clicked` to `onpbZatwierdzclicked`

Comment: I changed. But it doesn't work. I don't have an error: "No matching signal "
OUTPUT:
`QObject::connect: No such slot edytujklienta::onpbZatwierdzclicked((const QString&)) in ..\Recp\main.cpp:30
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'MainWindow')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'edytujklienta')
Wczytano numerID `
I don't have: `qDebug() << "Received number ID: " << text ; `

Comment: Have you changed it in the .h and in the .cpp? and use new syntax: `QObject::connect(&first, &MainWindow::newTextEntered, &second, &edytujklienta::onpbZatwierdzclicked)`

Comment: I used new syntax. :
`QObject::connect(&first, &MainWindow::newTextEntered, &second, &edytujklienta::onpbZatwierdzclicked);

`
OUTPUT:
`START 

QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pbZatwierdz_clicked()
START 

Opened! 
QObject::connect: No such signal MainWindow::on_leEdytujKlienta_returnPressed() in ..\Recp\mainwindow.cpp:47
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'leEdytujKlienta')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')
ODEBRANO numer ID:  "6"
Record zaktualizowany
Wczytano numerID 
`

Comment: show your .h and .cpp :), read [ask], and provide a decent [mcve]. do you understand?

Comment: also removes the build folder and recompiles the project

Comment: I want update data, but I got clear data.
`Imie=ui->leImie->text();`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is important. I'm a new here. I want to learn programming.

Comment: Do you have some button in your .ui file for class `edytujklienta` named exactly `pbZatwierdz`

Comment: Yes, I have button named pbZatwierdz in edytujklienta.ui

Comment: Is it in the `edytujklienta` class not the MainWindow? You probably should edit your question and add the .ui file used for the `edytujklienta` class

Comment: Yes. It is in the edytujklienta class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Qt5 style connect syntax, and connect to a lambda instead of a slot. The lambda can then use any call arguments you need.

I strongly advise against using connect-by-name for code maintenance reasons.